# Existance of FormData in window object

Tags: javascript

I was reading tutorials for "uploading images by Ajax". During this I saw

```
if(window.FormData){formdata = new FormData();}
```

As I'm using Google chrome so my browser supports `window.FormData`, but when I iterate window object by following code I don't see property named `FormData` in the list of properties,

```
for(prop in window) 
{
   document.write(prop+' : '+window[prop]+'<hr/>
}
```

What is the reason behind that behaviour, how do I see the existence of `window.FormData`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the reason behind this behaviour, however the first if statement that you provided is exactly the way to check for it's existence. If that if statement goes through, you can use window.FormData without problems.